# Is .ovpn file required for android OpenVpn client?

Tags: android, openvpn

I'm developing a commercial android vpn app like : [TurboVpn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.vpn.unblock.proxy.turbovpn&hl=en) or [ExpressVpn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expressvpn.vpn&hl=en)

I using OpenVpn protocol and my question is "Do i need to download .ovpn config file every time the user clicks "Connect" button ?"

OR is there any way to connect users to openvpn server without .ovpn file ?

I'm using [ICS-OPENVPN](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/) clinet.

Answer (score 0):

My experience indicates that once downloaded, the same file will work. Of course, my experience is as end-user.

Comment: do mean i have to create one .ovpn file for all users and download it once at the client side ?

Comment: If you don't have password and username hard-coded in there, yes, one is enough. Downloading once is enough (there is a way to read username/password from a text file)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to download your .ovpn file every time user click on the connect button. You can save your .ovpn file on local storage like shared preference, SQLite database or assets folder.

If you use API to download your ovpn file then it's better to save your file on shared preference or SQLite database but if you like to keep your file with the android app then use assets directory.

I have also developed an android vpn app based on the OpenVPN library and i store my all ovpn file on assets directory. My app is open source that's why I save ovpn file on the assets directory.

Give a look at my source code for better understanding.
https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN